# How to make specialized type classes for certain types, default implementation for the rest of types

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I would like to have a type class of types that can possibly casted to other types when possible.

```
class Castable a b where  
    cast :: a -> Maybe b  
    cast _ = Nothing -- default implementation
```

Now the class would be implemented for some types and for *all* the others I would like to have default implementation.

How one can do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not necessarily a safe or Haskell-y thing to do, but it is certainly possible, using [OverlappingInstances](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.3/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap)

First, enable them:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances  #-}
```

Write your casting class:

```
class Castable a b where  
    cast :: a -> Maybe b  
    cast _ = Nothing -- default implementation
```

An "optimized" instance:

```
instance Castable Int Bool where
        cast 0 = Just False
        cast _ = Just True
```

and finally, a general instance for all types:

```
instance Castable a b where
```

Example use:

```
main = do
    print $ (cast (7 :: Int) :: Maybe Bool)
    print $ (cast (7 :: Int) :: Maybe Integer)
```

Running this, the default is chosen when the types aren't specialized:

```
*Main> main
Just True
Nothing
```

Comment: In my case also {-# LANGUAGE IncoherentInstances #-} were needed, but this is the answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Don - how does the particular instance get chosen? i.e. does GHC always decide to use the most specific instance, especially in the presence of separate modules? There was a thread about this on Haskell Cafe a month or two ago, but no-one provided an answer.

Comment: According to the documentation: "The -XOverlappingInstances flag instructs GHC to allow more than one instance to match, provided there is a most specific one. If there is no most-specific match, the program is rejected."

Comment: What does most-specific mean here? I've read this a few times before but it was never clear to me.

Comment: Never mind my previous question. I think the docs have improved (or my ability to comprehend them). See: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-decls

Comment: Avoid IncoherentInstances at all costs.  Once you turn on that flag you no longer know which instance is going to be picked.