# Implement an O(log n) Foldable.elem for binary search trees in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Consider the following definition for binary trees:

```
data Tree a = Nil | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

The `Foldable` instance can be defined as follows:

```
instance Foldable Tree where
  foldr _ z Nil = z
  foldr f z (Node l d r) = foldr f (f d (foldr f z l)) r
```

But the problem is that the `elem` function runs in `O(n)` rather than `O(log n)`. When I try to implement a custom `elem`:

```
elem x Nil = False
elem x (Node l d r)
  | x == d = True
  | x < d = elem x l
  | otherwise = elem x r
```

I get `Could not deduce (Ord a) arising from a use of ‘<’`.
How can this problem be fixed?

Comment: For what it's worth: The corresponding function in `mono-traversable` is [`oelem`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.5.0/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#v:oelem), and as of version 1.0.5.0 it does have an efficient implementation for `Set`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use this `elem` method for the Foldable class, since the Foldable API requires the `elem` implementation for all of its instances to be able to search for any elements of any type with only an `Eq` instance.  "An `elem` that is polymorphic for all `Eq`" was an intentional choice in the design of the `Foldable` typeclass.

Your `elem` function, while very useful, is not compatible with the `elem` method for the `Foldable` typeclass, since it is not generic enough for the typeclass's desires.  The best way to export an `elem` function for your type would be to define a separate function outside of the typeclass.

Comment: I wonder if you could use a specialise pragma to provide a more efficient implementation for Ord instances

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake, `SPECIALIZE` isn't strong enough medicine. You'd need `RULES`, and you'd need one rewrite rule *per type*. It's horrible.

Comment: @dfeuer Spoken like a man who's been to hell and back. I wonder if anyone on the GHC team is working on this issue.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake, I don't think anyone really knows for sure what the right approach would even look like.

Comment: @dfeuer mono-traversable seems to use RULES for this - what makes that same approach not work here? https://github.com/snoyberg/mono-traversable/blob/c41e5dc98457ea284a7d6f29faf3127b8f99f429/mono-traversable/src/Data/MonoTraversable.hs#L850

Comment: @ChrisMartin, there are two problems with `RULES`: 1. As I mention above, you need a rule for every `Ord` type you wish to optimize; as a corollary, users accustomed to the function being efficient may be surprised when they use a different type and suddenly it isn't. 2. Rules aren't guaranteed to fire, and never will do so unless optimizations are enabled; this could be bad for the edit/compile/test cycle.

Comment: How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607372/how-to-make-specialized-type-classes-for-certain-types-default-implementation-f